# How do I configure mutt to display the date header in my local time zone in the pager?

Tags: bash, shell-script, configuration, email, mutt

When I view a message in the pager mutt displays the time in the Date header in UTC rather than my local time zone. The index view displays the local time correctly. I found [this old mailing list post](http://marc.info/?l=mutt-users&m=103168474726643&w=2) that describes how to get the local time to display in the status bar at the bottom of the screen, but this still doesn't "fix" the time in the Date header at the top of the screen. Is there any way to get the pager to convert the Date header time to local time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.muttrc` add the following line:

```
set display_filter="exec sed -r \"s/^Date:\\s*(([F-Wa-u]{3},\\s*)?[[:digit:]]{1,2}\\s+[A-Sa-y]{3}\\s+[[:digit:]]{4}\\s+[[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2}(:[[:digit:]]{1,2})?\\s+[+-][[:digit:]]{4})/date +'Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z' -d '\\1'/e\""
```

This will change the `Date:` header in the message (for display only) to your local timezone if the header contained a valid RFC formatted date.  If the provided date format was incorrect (we are dealing with untrusted user input after all) it will be preserved.  To combat a possible attempt to inject the shell code through the header the `sed` pattern implements a whitelist based on RFC 5322 (this RFC defines the format of the `Date:` field).

Note that `mutt` limits the command line to be no more than 255 character long, hence I optimised the original `sed` command that had stricter whitelist to fit into 255 bytes.  If you plan to do other things with the message, then the full `sed` command you can put in a script is:

```
sed -r "s/^Date:\s*(((Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\s*)?[[:digit:]]{1,2}\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+[[:digit:]]{4}\s+[[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2}(:[[:digit:]]{1,2})?\s+[+-][[:digit:]]{4})/date +'Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z' -d '\1'/e"
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to make that work on macOS? I would like to include that in my `filter.sed` file. Thanks!

Comment: There is not, unless you are using GNU sed (e.g. via Homebrew) -- the above `sed` commands rely on the `e` modifier to the `s` command.  That modifier is a GNU extension and macOS'es `sed` is the BSD one.

Comment: Answer by @viric is good. No need to change message via filter.

Comment: @Jangid, please read the original request and it specifically asks for the proper display of a local zone in the _top_ of the page and not in the status line.

Comment: @galaxy Oh! yes. Just noticed that. Correct.

Comment: You're the best. AroOoOOund. And you're never gonna let us down!

Answer (score 12):

The formatting in the index is controlled by the `index_format` setting -- it's generated by mutt. The `Date` header isn't controlled by mutt, it's a header included with the message that just gets displayed. If it shows UTC time it's because the sending server decided to use UTC when generating the header. The only way to change it is to actually change the message itself, either when you receive it or when you view it.

Changing it as it comes in means adding a filter to your mail delivery agent, but it needs to be sophisticated enough to parse the existing `Date` header and rewrite it. It's almost certainly better to just have mutt reformat the message when you look at it. You can set the [`display_filter`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#display_filter) property to an executable file, and it will pipe any message you open through the executable before displaying it.

You'll need to write a program or shell script that reads each line of the message and replaces the one with the Date header, or find an existing script (there's one [here](http://markmail.org/message/4ga5vyu43aym6hwd) that might work, although it doesn't seem like it should really be necessary to involve a temporary file)

Answer (score 8):

http://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg44341.html

This suggests using the 'pager_format', to make it show the letter date in the local timezone:

set pager_format="%4C %Z %[!%b %e at %I:%M %p]  %.20n  %s%* -- (%P)"

Comment: This works very well, also for index_format.

Answer (score 6):

Obligatory Perl solution that preserves the "Date" header while adding an extra "Local-Date" header to contain the localtime version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

use Date::Parse;
use POSIX;
use strict;

if (/^Date: (.*)$/) {
    my $datestr = $1;
    my $date = strftime ("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S",
                         localtime (str2time ($datestr)));
    print "Local-Date: $date\n";
}

print;
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking Gilles' advice, here's a version that uses a temp file and `formail`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

# save the message to a file
cat - >"$TMPFILE"
# extract the date header
DATE=$( formail -xDate: < "$TMPFILE" )
# convert to the current timezone (defined by TZ)
DATE=$( date -R -d "$DATE" )
# output the modified message
echo "Date: $DATE"
formail -fI Date < "$TMPFILE"
# clean up
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

Comment: This is susceptible to code injection attacks through a malformed `Date:` header -- if you go into a subshell you need to validate/sanitise the input.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a procmail solution:

```
# extract date from mail
:0
TMPDATE=| formail -x Date

# get local date
LOCALDATE=`date --rfc-2822 -d "$TMPDATE"`

# add it new header to the mail
:0 f
| formail -I "LocalDate: $LOCALDATE"
```

And display LocalDate: in muttrc:

```
unignore localdate
```

Comment: how do you invoke this?

Answer (score 2):

`set display_filter="/PATH/TO/THIS/PYTHON/FILE"` in your `.muttrc`.

Python 3.3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import re
# import subprocess
from email.utils import format_datetime, parsedate_to_datetime

in_headers = True
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    if line == "\n": in_headers = False
    match = re.match(r'^Date: (.+)', line)

    if not in_headers or not match:
        print(line, end="")
        continue

    date_string = match.group(1)
    # use this if you do not have python 3.3+
    # converted_date = subprocess.Popen(['date','-d',date_string], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
    converted_date = format_datetime(parsedate_to_datetime(date_string).astimezone(tz=None))
    print('Date:', converted_date)
```

Comment: The commented line is susceptible to code injection attacks through a malformed `Date:` header -- if you go into a subshell you need to validate/sanitise the input, otherwise the script is OK from the security standpoint.  However, it is quite heavy for a script that runs on every message you browse.

Answer (score 0):

I made a shell script as described at the end of Michael's answer that does the job for me:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    if [[ "${LINE}" =~ ^Date:\ .* ]]; then
        DATE=${LINE#Date: }
        # convert to the current timezone (defined by TZ)
        DATE=$(date -d "${DATE}")
        printf '%s' "Date: ${DATE}"
    elif [[ -n $LINE ]]; then
      # We've reach the end of the headers, so stop parsing
      echo
      exec cat
    else
        printf '%s\n' "${LINE}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Parsing emails is pretty tricky. I recommend using a dedicated tool like `formail` (part of the [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) package) or `reformail` (part of [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/)) to extract the existing `Date:` header and put a new one in place. Take care of edge cases such as a missing or malformatted `Date:` header.