# Using corrected time in the "attribution" variable of mutt?

Tags: configuration, time, mutt

I receive quite a few email messages displaying UTC time within the "Date:" header.
I found the following perl script by user hyperair, very useful to display 
a new header "Local-Date" for incoming messages:

[How do I configure mutt to display the date header in my local time zone in the pager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18651/how-do-i-configure-mutt-to-display-the-date-header-in-my-local-time-zone-in-the/80228#80228)

However when replying I still have to fix manually the time displayed on the 
attribution line.

How can one set up the variable "attribution" to use the time used in the
new header "Local-Date"?

(below I have copied the perl script which I use with as "display_filter")

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

use Date::Parse;
use POSIX;
use strict;

if (/^Date: /) {
    my $datestr = substr ($_, length ("Date: "));
    my $date = strftime ("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%m:%S",
                         localtime (str2time ($datestr)));
    print "Local-Date: $date\n";
}

print;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think setting

`set attribution="On %[!%e %b at %H:%M ], %n <%a> wrote:"`

will suffice to display the local time on the attribution line,
usually inserted at the beginning of the quoted text of a reply.

I have actually imitated the format used by user viric for the variable
'pager_format' in [How do I configure mutt to display the date header in my local time zone in the pager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18651/how-do-i-configure-mutt-to-display-the-date-header-in-my-local-time-zone-in-the/80228#80228)