# Change reply template ("On $date, $sender wrote:")

Tags: mutt

When replying to an email, Mutt inserts a line like this:

> On $day $month, $sender wrote:

and puts the sender's mail below.

I'd like to change that, specifically I'd like to add the time of the sender's email.

Does Mutt offer a setting to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the setting is [`attribution`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#attribution), which by default is

```
"On %d, %n wrote:"
```

There are [a variety of substitutions available](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#index-format); `%d` is supposed to represent the date *and time* of the message you’re replying to. The format used for the date and time is determined by [the `date_format` setting](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#date-format).

You can change these settings by editing your `.muttrc`:

```
set attribution="On %d, %n wrote:"
set date_format="!%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M:%S%p %Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Stephen Kitt's helpful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553101/change-reply-template-on-date-sender-wrote#553102) I added this to my `muttrc`:

```
set attribution="On %[!%F at %T], %n (%a) wrote:"
```

Which produces a line like this in the reply:

> On 2019-11-20 at 19:31:16, The Sender (sender@domain.com) wrote:

I first tried to set `date_format` using Mutt's [hooks](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#hooks) (`reply-hook` and `folder-hook`) in order to use `%d` in both `attribution` and the `index_format` but still have different time formats for index and `attribution`. This worked until returning to the index from replying to a message: The index would now show the same time format as the attribution line in the message reply.

Since there doesn't seem to be a `post-reply-hook` or a hook that's executed when showing the index, I used the square brackets to format the date in the `attribution` setting, something I learned how to do [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246553/using-corrected-time-in-the-attribution-variable-of-mutt#246609).